# How To Destroy CoundownTimer in Java when the button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I make a timer with a count time of 5 seconds, then when I press the exit button the counter automatically stops?

Here is my timer code:

```
    public void startTimer(final long finish, long tick) {
        CountDownTimer t;
        t = new CountDownTimer(finish, tick) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long remainedSecs = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                textTimer.setText("" + (remainedSecs / 60) + ":" + (remainedSecs % 60));// manage it accordign to you
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                textTimer.setText("00:00");
                Toast.makeText(FloatingVideoWidgetShowService.this, "Waktu Habis", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                long seek = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
                videoView.setKeepScreenOn(false);
                stopSelf();
                WritableMap args = new Arguments().createMap();
                args.putInt("index", index);
                args.putInt("seek", (int) seek);
                args.putString("url", playingVideo.getString("url"));
                args.putString("type", "close");

                sendEvent(reactContext, "onClose", args);
                onDestroy();
                cancel();
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

And this is my code when pressing the stop / exit button :

```
        floatingWindow.findViewById(R.id.btn_deny).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                long seek = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
                videoView.setKeepScreenOn(false);
                stopSelf();
                WritableMap args = new Arguments().createMap();
                args.putInt("index", index);
                args.putInt("seek", (int) seek);
                args.putString("url", playingVideo.getString("url"));
                args.putString("type", "close");

                sendEvent(reactContext, "onClose", args);
                onDestroy();
            }
        });
```

How so when btn_deny is clicked Cuntdowntimer stops and does not force close?

Thanks.

Comment: Try ```countDownTimer.cancel();```. You'll need to declare countDownTimer outside the function in order to do this thou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `onDestroy()` to close your activity or fragment. Instead, you need to call `finish()`.

To close the `CountDownTimer`, you need to make it a class scope variable. Prepare the timer at your `startTimer` then stop the timer by calling `t.cancel()` like the following code:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
   // Declare the variable to be accessed later.
   CountDownTimer t;

   ...

   public void startTimer(final long finish, long tick) {
     t = new CountDownTimer(finish, tick) {
         ...
     }.start();

   }


   private void yourOtherMethod() {

    floatingWindow.findViewById(R.id.btn_deny).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
          if(t != null) t.cancel();
          ...
       }
    });
   }

}
```